# Displaying measures and labels of angles at the same distance from their vertices

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the measures for two angles and the labels `x`, `y`, and `z` for three other angles. I use the `angles` package to them.  How do I get them at the same distance from their vertices?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (-4,0);

%These commands position vertex C so that the line through A and C is inclined at an angle of 95 degrees
%and the line through B and C is inclined at an angle of 58 degrees.  Since there are 180 degrees in a
%triangle, the measure of angle ACB is 37 degrees.
\path[name path=A-to-C] (A) -- (95:7.5);
\path[name path=B-to-C] (B) -- ++(58:7.5);
\path[name intersections={of= A-to-C and B-to-C, by=C}];

%These commands draws the triangle.
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;

%This command draws a line segment horizontally rightwards from A.
\coordinate (D) at (3,0);
\draw (A) -- (D);

%This command draws a line segment upwards from C.
\draw (C) -- ++(95:1.5) coordinate (E);

%This command draws a line segment upwards from C.
\draw (B) -- ++(-122:1.5) coordinate (F);

%These commands draw the angles for the display.
\path pic[angle radius=5mm,"$\scriptstyle{x}$",angle eccentricity=1.25] {angle = D--A--C};
\path pic[angle radius=5mm,"$\scriptstyle{37}$",angle eccentricity=1.25] {angle = B--C--A};
\path pic[angle radius=5mm,"$\scriptstyle{58}$",angle eccentricity=1.25] {angle = A--B--C};
\path pic[angle radius=5mm,"$\scriptstyle{y}$",angle eccentricity=1.25] {angle = E--C--B};
\path pic[angle radius=5mm,"$\scriptstyle{z}$",angle eccentricity=1.25] {angle = F--B--A};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Put `draw` in all of them, you will see that they are equidistant from the vertex, only the height is different.

Comment: [As in this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gOJp7.png)

Comment: @Harish Kumar  I am the victim of an optical illusion.

Comment: It happens to every one, especially after long hours in front of monitor `:-)`

Comment: That is why you should use `draw` in such places and then remove it after you are done.

Comment: @Harish Kumar   I agree - I should first view the paths using `\draw`.  I think it is a useful post to have on the web site, though.  Thanks for your help.